# How do I change a certain percentage of black patches green in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I was wondering if someone would be able to help my write code for Netlogo that changes a certain percentage of random black patches green within a certain radius of the middle patch. Thanks!

Comment: Look at `in-radius` and `random-float`.

Comment: Why do you need random-float?

Comment: Thanks! We're looking to turn a certain percentage of roofs green for an ecological study.

Comment: @mattsap Your approach matches the specification if the circles are large enough.  It enforces the percentage for each circle, assuming the circle contains enough patches.  However, `n-of` will round down.  You could use random-float to match the specification more precisely in an average circle (if there are many, or across simulations).  To see the potential problem, suppose that your radius is 1 and the percentage is 10%.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, ask n-of them where n is the number of patches you're going to change with respect to that percentage you specified.

```
  let radius 5
  let percentage .5
  ask patch 0 0
  [
    let close-patches patches in-radius radius with [pcolor = black]
    ask  n-of (percentage * count close-patches) close-patches
    [set pcolor green]
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give it a try.